# Android App crashes once my list contains 3 items

Tags: java, android, arrays, list

I tried to build my first Android app (a noobish Snake remake) and I noticed the program always crashes once my Snake reaches a length of 3.

Every part of my snake is stored in a class called "Segment", which stores the x and y coordinates and the lifetime of this bodypart.

```
static List<Segment> list = new ArrayList<Segment>();{  //my list
    Segment startingSegment = new Segment(0, 0, 1);     //adding starting element to my list
    list.add(startingSegment);
}
```

For test reasons I made a special loop which adds elements to my list:

```
while(list.size() < 2){                          //this works
    Segment newSegment = new Segment(0, 0, 1);
    list.add(newSegment);
}

while(list.size() < 3){                          //this crashes the app already
    Segment newSegment = new Segment(0, 0, 1);
    list.add(newSegment);
}
```

Logcat:

```
    04-05 15:50:19.921: E/AndroidRuntime(14308): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-3556 04-05 
15:50:19.921: E/AndroidRuntime(14308): Process: com.example.snake, PID: 14308 04-05
 15:50:19.921: E/AndroidRuntime(14308): java.util.ConcurrentModificationException 04-05 
15:50:19.921: E/AndroidRuntime(14308): at 
java.example.ArrayList$ArrayListIterator.next(ArrayList.java:573)
```

I really don't know what's going on there and would appreciate some help.

Comment: 04-05 15:50:19.921: E/AndroidRuntime(14308): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-3556
04-05 15:50:19.921: E/AndroidRuntime(14308): Process: com.example.snake, PID: 14308
04-05 15:50:19.921: E/AndroidRuntime(14308): java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
04-05 15:50:19.921: E/AndroidRuntime(14308):  at java.example.ArrayList$ArrayListIterator.next(ArrayList.java:573)

Comment: Read more from the logcat and it will say to you the line, anyway the problem is caused by the fact you are adding/removing elements from the arraylist while you read it using an iterator

Comment: try synchronized in all function which is using list

Comment: This can help you if you have a concurrency issues http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html

Comment: You should use Iterator

Comment: @Vetal.lebed That won't neccessarily protect you from concurrent modification exception.

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6866238/concurrent-modification-exception-adding-to-an-arraylist

Comment: Thank you for your link o0rebelious0o, that was exactly what I was looking for. Program works fine now c:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was removing items from my list while iterating through it. Making a second "toRemove" list fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

`I really don't know what's going on there and would appreciate some help.`

What's going on here is that you've created a shared `List` object, and are trying to access it from multiple threads without any proper synchronization. This results in exception. Consider using synchronized list wrapper around your list:

`List<Segment> list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Segment>());`

That should solve your problem in case you only add and remove items. If you're going to iterate the list, you will also have to play a bit more with synchronization, as the iteration on a synchronized collection is not thread-safe.