# Custom Filtering throws Null Pointer exception in getView(). even after doing all neccessary null checks

Tags: android, filtering, autocompletetextview

Before I was getting Concurrent Modification Exception. I avoided it, by creating a new arraylist. But, now I'm getting a Null pointer exception & strange thing is that I've done all neccessary null checks. Still I don't understand What might went wrong.

Here is my publishResults() method:

```
@Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            if (constraint != null) {
                mSuggestions.clear();
                for (Item item : mItemsAll) {
                    try {
                        if (item.name.toLowerCase(Locale.US).startsWith(constraint.toString().toLowerCase(Locale.US))) {
                            mSuggestions.add(item);
                        }
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                    }
                }
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                filterResults.values = mSuggestions;
                filterResults.count = mSuggestions.size();
                return filterResults;
            } else {
                return new FilterResults();
            }
        }
```

Here mItemsAll holds the copy of the mainList given to the adapter

```
@Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            ArrayList<Item> filteredList = (ArrayList<Item>) results.values;
            if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                clear();
                for (Item c : filteredList) {
                    add(c);
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        }
    };
```

results contains the filtered results obtained from the `performFiltering().

```
clear()`- clears all the elements of the main list given to the adapter &  `add(c), adds the filtered list to the list.
```

I was getting  Concurrent Modification exceptio at this line:

```
for (Item c : filteredList)
```

So I removed this line:
`ArrayList<Item> filteredList = (ArrayList<Item>) results.values;`
& added these lines

```
ArrayList<Item> filteredList = new ArrayList<Item>();
                filteredList.addAll((Collection<? extends Item>) results.values);
```

But now I'm getting Null Pointer exception in the getview method. But according to my code, it should go to the getview, only if the filtered resuls has some values. then Why I'm getting this exception?

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: What is results.values? What does clear() do. What does add(Item) do? Infact, if it is possible to add the whole code structure involved, that would help.

Comment: Can you post the `filter()` method? My guess is that you're tinkering with the original adapter items in it. If that's the case the collection you're adding items to is actually the FilterResults, which will cause that exception of course.

@Knossos that's (probably) a subclass of [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html).

Comment: This has already been answerd here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6866238/concurrent-modification-exception-adding-to-an-arraylist

Comment: Although the concept of the question is a common one, the exact reason for this question is not answered in your link.