# Copying a double ArrayList in Java using a loop

Tags: java, function, loops, arraylist, double

So, I have tried to create a loop in Java that I want to copy my list of lists of cells, however I get the error `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` the second time the inner loop is run. Any ideas why?

Here is the code:

```
private ArrayList<ArrayList<Cell>> copyBoard(ArrayList<ArrayList<Cell>> board) {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Cell>> copiedBoard = null;
    for (ArrayList<Cell> array : board) {
        int i = 0;
        for (Cell cell : board.get(i)) {
            Cell copiedCell = new Cell();
            copiedCell = cell;
            array.add(copiedCell);
            i++;
        }
        copiedBoard.add(array);
    }
    return copiedBoard;
}
```

Comment: Please paste your code into the question. Do not put it on an external site.

Comment: (1) `Cell copiedCell = new Cell()` – The newly created cell is not used, the next statement overwrites the cell. (2) `copiedBoard.add(array)` this will throw a `NullPointerException`, because it is not initialized. Initialize the `ArrayList` first using `ArrayList<ArrayList<Cell>> copiedBoard = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Cell>>()`.

Answer (score 0):

One problem you have with your code is that `copiedBoard` is never initialized.

Comment: Thanks guys, I realized some errors in the first post, thanks to you guys.

Answer (score 0):

You're not allowed to modify a generic collection while iterating forward throughout it. Iterate backwards: this way, you save time and space w/o having to copy the collection to a different location.

```
private ArrayList<ArrayList<Cell>> copyBoard(ArrayList<ArrayList<Cell>> board) {
  ArrayList<ArrayList<Cell>> copiedBoard = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Cell>>(); //initialize it

    for(int i = board.length - 1; i>=0; i--){
        ArrayList<Cell> collection = new ArrayList<Cell>();
        for(int j = board.get(i).length - 1; j>=0; j--){
          Cell cell = board.get(i).get(j);
          collection.add(copiedCell);
        }
    }
    copiedBoard.add(collection);
  }

  return copiedBoard;
}
```

Comment: You are allowed to modify an ArrayList while iterating over it, just not within an enhanced for loop.

Comment: Read again. Try iterating forward with a simple for.

Comment: Well, iterating with a java.lang.Iterator, you're right. I was responding to the *concept* of iterating, not the Iterator object.

Comment: I was referring to the fact that forward iteration throughout a generic collection having objects added or removed is not permitted. Edited to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

The enhanced for loop you are using, is only a language construct that the compiler internally translates to an Iterator.
While you are iterating a collection, you are not allowed to modify it directly, but only via the Iterator's methods.

In line 6 your are effectively getting an iterator on the list that you already retrieved in line 4. So as of line 6 you are iterating the list, that you are then modifying in line 9 via .add().

You can fix it by creating the iterator yourself, and then using the Iterator's modification methods to insert elements.

Answer (score 0):

Because it is illegal to add to/delete from something being iterated in an enhanced for loop (or with an java.util.Iterator)

- *[Concurrent Modification Exception : adding to an ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6866238/concurrent-modification-exception-adding-to-an-arraylist)*
- https://www.google.com/search?q=concurrent+modification+exception+for+each+loop
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html
- *[Iterating through a Collection, avoiding ConcurrentModificationException when removing in loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223918/iterating-through-a-list-avoiding-concurrentmodificationexception-when-removing)*

Here is an answer I wrote aboout the differences between the traditional and enhanced for loops: *[How does the Java 'for each' loop work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85190/how-does-the-java-for-each-loop-work/22114571#22114571)*

Chane your loop(s) to the traditional for loop and it will work fine...as long as you appropriately update the index counter.

Answer (score 0):

This code does not really copy the cell:

```
Cell copiedCell = new Cell();
copiedCell = cell;
```

You are just assigning the same object... You should read this: [How do I copy an object in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869033/how-do-i-copy-an-object-in-java)