# Removing an object from a list while also running another list returns error

Tags: java, foreach, iteration

So with this code I am going trough a list and removing an object.

```
    public void setUpgradeClicked(){
    for (Iterator<Upgrade> iterator = displayedUpgrades.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        Upgrade u = iterator.next();
        if (u.clicked) {
            iterator.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

And at the same time this code is running

```
        for(Upgrade u : displayedUpgrades){
        u.dostuff();
    }
```

So ofcourse I would get an ConcurrentModificationException error but I'd like to fix it, I have no idea how to do it though.

If someone could help me with this that would be great.

Comment: Don't run both loops simultaneously?

Comment: This confuses the iterator as it already has to go through the loop and meanwhile you are messing with it. You can simply create a new List of your Upgrade objects. I will paste an answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add while iterating. the best thing is make a child list of the items to be added during iteration and then use the child list to do the desired operation

Please refer [Concurrent Modification Exception : adding to an ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6866238/concurrent-modification-exception-adding-to-an-arraylist)

http://durgaprasadtechie.blogspot.com/2011/07/concurrentmodificationexception-fail.html

Answer (score 0):

```
synchronized(u){
  if (u.clicked) {
    iterator.remove();
  }
}

synchronized(u){
  u.dostuff();
}
```

*synchronized* can good work with multi-thread.You can search it for more detail.