# method giving Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException error

Tags: java

I am getting the following error

> java purse transfer method giving Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException error

when executing the following method:

```
public void transfer1(Purse p) {
    for (String coin : newPurse) {
        newPurse.add(coin);
        p.newPurse.clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concurrent Modification Exception : adding to an ArrayList](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6866238/concurrent-modification-exception-adding-to-an-arraylist)

Comment: This comes because you want to make changes in the list, you are currently iterating over. You can do this with an iterator, but not with an forEach loop. Also I am not quite sure, what you want to accomplish with your code. Look at the linked question from radoh.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concurrent Modification exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496180/concurrent-modification-exception)