# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException with custom ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Of course i know what does this error mean, but i don't know how to remove this.
Now i'm trying with

```
 private void removeFriendFromList() {
    List<Friend> copy = new ArrayList<Friend>(globalSearchFriends);
    for (Friend friend : globalSearchFriends) {
        if (friend.equals(remove)) {
            copy.remove(friend);
        }
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work.
This is my globallist

```
 private List<Friend> globalSearchFriends = new ArrayList<>();
```

I'm trying iterating too, but it didn't work or i did something bad.

Also i need to use it here: where i search for a friend in api, this is working like when i input text in EditText then in my adapter i see that user, but this work only for few members, always when i search like "andrew" and then i search "youko" i get the error.

```
private void serachFriend(final String query) {

    etGlobalSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcherAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            FindFriend request = new FindFriend();
            request.query = query;
            request.query = s.toString().toLowerCase().trim();
            backend.findFriend(request).enqueue(new Callback<ResponseFindFriend>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<ResponseFindFriend> call, Response<ResponseFindFriend> response) {
                    synchronized (globalSearchFriends) {
                        globalSearchFriends.clear();
                        removeFriendFromList();
                        try {
                            if (response == null)
                                throw new Exception();
                            if (!response.isSuccessful())
                                throw new Exception();
                            if (response.body() == null)
                                throw new Exception();
                            if (response.body().results == null)
                                throw new Exception();
                            globalSearchFriends = response.body().results;
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.d("Blad", "sobie");
                        } finally {
                            gatherResults();
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<ResponseFindFriend> call, Throwable t) {
                    synchronized (globalSearchFriends) {
                        globalSearchFriends.clear();
                        removeFriendFromList();
                        gatherResults();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

private void removeFriendFromList() {
    List<Friend> copy = new ArrayList<Friend>(globalSearchFriends);
    for (Friend friend : globalSearchFriends) {
        if (friend.equals(remove)) {
            copy.remove(friend);
        }
    }
}

private void gatherResults() {
    removeFriendFromList();
    for (Friend f : globalSearchFriends)
        globalSearchFriends.add(f);
    findedFriendsAdapter.setFriendList(globalSearchFriends);
}
```

Any kind of help associated, Have a nice day! :)

Edit
I got error on this case.

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
   for (Friend f : globalSearchFriends)
        globalSearchFriends.add(f);
    findedFriendsAdapter.setFriendList(globalSearchFriends);
```

And on log i have:

```
   at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListIterator.next
```

Comment: You should use iterator when modifying a list while iterating it.

Comment: Please provide a **real** [mcve] with a matching stack trace. When iterating one list, removing elements from another list should just work. So I assume that your code is only showing parts of the truth. And just for the record: you  did **override** equals in your Friends class?

Comment: @jitinsharma He is **not** modifying the list while iterating. He is manipulating a **copy** of that list!

Comment: `globalSearchFriends.clear(); 
                        removeFriendFromList();` The list is already empty, which you are iterating.

Comment: I don't understand `removeFriendFromList` function. And meaning of calling `globalSearchFriends.clear();
                        removeFriendFromList();`

Comment: @Nizam But then the **iteration** in his helper method would iterate an **empty** list nothing; and thus no iteration at all, and no call to remove(). I think we are wasting our time explaining an observation ... that can not be explained with the code he is swowing.

Comment: what i must to show more?

Comment: Well, he is updating the list, but in the other method ;) this is obvious with the exception... that why it should always be present. You iterate a list then add each element in this same list.

Comment: I told you. Please read about [mcve]! And: the stack trace!

Comment: @jitinsharma Wrong. It is more error prone to modify a list while iterating it with `Iterator`. See this http://stackoverflow.com/a/6866271/2709580

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds suspicious:

```
for (Friend f : globalSearchFriends)
    globalSearchFriends.add(f);
```

You try to add the content of `globalSearchFriends` to itself while iterating which is not allowed with an `ArrayList` thus it leads to a `ConcurrentModificationException`. Indeed [`ArrayList#iterator()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#iterator--) returns a [fail-fast iterator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#fail-fast) which means that:

> If the list is **structurally modified** at any time **after the iterator is
>   created**, in any way except through the iterator's own `remove` or `add`
>   methods, the iterator will throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

It doesn't sound like a normal/expected behavior but if you really wand to duplicate the content of the list simply use [`addAll(Collection<? extends E> c)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-) instead of iterating as next:

```
globalSearchFriends.addAll(globalSearchFriends);
// or globalSearchFriends.addAll(new ArrayList<>(globalSearchFriends)); for safety
findedFriendsAdapter.setFriendList(globalSearchFriends);
```

**NB:** An `ArrayList` is not thread-safe so ensure to call `addAll(Collection<? extends E> c)` on the list if and only if the list is not shared or under the protection of an explicit or intrinsic lock otherwise you will get an unpredictable behavior.

Comment: AddAll is not guaranteed to work: "the behavior of this call is undefined if the specified collection is this list, and this list is nonempty."

Comment: @Joni of course since `ArrayList` is not thread safe but here it is not the issue as it is done within a synchronized block

Comment: Yea this helped me. problem is that i use one list to everything, now when i create new list for findedFrieds im now have a problem with that. Thanks u helped me a lot :)

Comment: @Joni I added an NB for this

Comment: Read the documentation of the addAll method: Threads and locks have nothing to do with it. `list.addAll(list)` is not guaranteed to work, even though with the current implementation it does. (Maybe this is a documentation bug?)

Comment: @Joni `addAll` of an `ArrayList` get the content of the collection as an array then does an array copy so only a concurrent modification of the list between the `toArray` and the `System.arraycopy` will cause an unexpected behavior which will not happen if concurrent modifications are prevented

Answer (score 0):

how about CopyOnWrite Collection  ?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    CopyOnWriteArrayList<Integer> list = new CopyOnWriteArrayList();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        list.add(i);
    }

    for (Integer num : list) {
        if (num % 2 == 0) {
            list.add(num * 100);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("list = " + list);
}
```

output
list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 200, 400, 600, 800]

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
   private void removeFriendFromList() {
     List<Friend> copy = new ArrayList<Friend>(globalSearchFriends);
     Friend targetToRemove = null;
     for (Friend friend : globalSearchFriends) {
       if (friend.equals(remove)) {
         targetToRemove = friend;
       }
     }
     if (targetToRemove != null) {
       copy.remove(targetToRemove);
     }
   }
```