# ConcurrentModificationException Minigame

Tags: java, exception, java.util.concurrent, concurrentmodification

**Hello.**

**I'm running a server and have added a minigame.**

**whenever the game is about to start.. it calls onStart() first. Now I get ConcurrentModificationException on this line:**

```
for(Player p : waiting) {
```

**And here is the method:**

```
    public void onStart() {
    trawler.players.clear();
    for(Player p : waiting) {
        if(!boat.playerInArea(p)) {
            waiting.remove(p);
        }
    }

    for(Player p : waiting) {
        trawler.players.add(p);
    }

    trawler.start();
    waiting.clear();
}
```

**if you need the classes, here they are:**

**TrawlerWaitingRoom.java:**

```
package server.model.minigames.trawler;

import server.model.players.Location;
import server.model.players.Player;

public class TrawlerWaitingRoom extends WaitingRoom {
private Trawler trawler;
//private Location boat = new Location(2668,2674,3165,3185);
private Location boat = new Location(2808, 2811,3415,3425);


public TrawlerWaitingRoom(Trawler trawler) {
    super(1, 2);
    this.trawler = trawler;
}

@Override
public boolean startGame() {
    if(trawler.inProgress()) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    trawler.players.clear();
    for(Player p : waiting) {
        if(!boat.playerInArea(p)) {
            waiting.remove(p);
        }
    }

    for(Player p : waiting) {
        trawler.players.add(p);
    }

    trawler.start();
    waiting.clear();
}

@Override
public void onLeave(Player p) {
    p.asClient().getPA().movePlayer(2804, 3421, 0);
    //p.asClient().getPA().movePlayer(2676, 3170, 0);
}

@Override
public void onJoin(Player p) {
    p.asClient().getPA().movePlayer(2808, 3421, 1);
    //p.asClient().getPA().movePlayer(2672, 3170, 1);
    if(!isActive()) {
        p.asClient().sendMessage(trawler.getGameTime() == 0 ? "The trawler will be returning in less than a minute!" : "The trawler will return in "+trawler.getGameTime() + (trawler.getGameTime() == 1 ? " minute" : " minutes")+"!");
    } else {
        p.asClient().sendMessage(getTimeRemaining() == 0 ? "The trawler will be leaving in less than a minute!" : "The trawler will leave in "+ getTimeRemaining() + (getTimeRemaining() == 1 ? " minute" : " minutes")+"!");
    }
}

@Override
public Location getLocation() {
    return boat;
}

@Override
public void onTimeChange() {
    for(Player p : waiting) {
        if(!isActive()) {
            p.asClient().sendMessage(trawler.getGameTime() == 0 ? "The trawler will be returning in less than a minute!" : "The trawler will return in "+trawler.getGameTime() + (trawler.getGameTime() == 1 ? " minute" : " minutes")+"!");
        } else {
            p.asClient().sendMessage(getTimeRemaining() == 0 ? "The trawler will be leaving in less than a minute!" : "The trawler will leave in "+ getTimeRemaining() + (getTimeRemaining() == 1 ? " minute" : " minutes")+"!");
        }
    }
}

@Override
public boolean canStart() {
    if(trawler.inProgress()) {
        return false;
    }
    if(waiting.size() < minimumPlayers) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

**GroupMinigame.java:**

```
package server.model.minigames.trawler;

import server.model.minigames.trawler.WaitingRoom;

public abstract class GroupMinigame {

public abstract WaitingRoom getWaitingRoom();

public abstract String getWaitingRoomMessage();
}
```

**WaitingRoom.java:**
http://pastebin.com/KkC8ReWV

**Trawler.java:**
http://pastebin.com/XW5XrsjR

**Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the problem:

```
for(Player p : waiting) {
    if(!boat.playerInArea(p)) {
        waiting.remove(p); // BOOM
    }
}
```

You can't directly modify a collection you're iterating over.

Instead, you must use an [`Iterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html):

```
for(Iterator<Player> i = waiting.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
    Player p = i.next(); 
    if(!boat.playerInArea(p)) {
        i.remove(); // Allowed with an iterator
    }
}
```

Comment: Now, this resolved my problem but it's not adding me to the trawler.players list. 

  for(Player p : waiting) {
   trawler.players.add(p);
  }

Answer (score 0):

You're creating an iterator on an object, by using a `for-each` loop. You're then trying to edit it, which is not permitted in Java.

```
for(Player p : waiting) {
    // Iterator created.
    if(!boat.playerInArea(p)) {
        // Change to iterated object.
        waiting.remove(p);
    }
}
```

Your alternative is to create a new list, and overwrite the old list. For example:

```
private List<Waiting> newWaiting = new ArrayList<Waiting>();

for(Player p : waiting) {
   // Iterator created on the WAITING object.
   if(boat.playerInArea(p)) {
       newWaiting.add(p);
       // Logic is flipped, so those that pass are carried forward.
   }
}
waiting = newWaiting;
// Set waiting's reference to point to newWaiting's reference.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Iterator#remove()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove%28%29) to remove elements from `List` while iterating through the `List`.

```
Iterator<Player> itr = waiting.iterator();
while(itr.hasNext()) {
    Player p = itr.next(); 
    if(!boat.playerInArea(p)) {
      itr.remove(); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's rather simple: You're removing objects from the list `waiting`, while you use it as a loop. That's not allowed.
Try the following instead:

```
List<Player> temporaryList = new LinkedList<Player>(waiting);
for(Player p : temporaryList ) {
    if(!boat.playerInArea(p)) {
        waiting.remove(p);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two logical steps you need to follow before correcting and understanding this error.

1. [How does the Java 'for each' loop work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85190/how-does-the-java-for-each-loop-work) (Hint: Iterator)
2. How can the use of an iterator lead to a  [Concurrent Modification exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496180/concurrent-modification-exception) ?