# ConcurrentModificationException: Need help understanding "synchronized"

Tags: android, concurrency

The following method throws a ConcurrentModificationException because the list it iterates over gets modified. Can I use synchronised to lock... something... either while the list is modified or iterated over?

How would I go about doing that? I've tried a few ways but none of them seem to work. Locking "this" doesn't work, for instance.

```
public class Deck extends ArrayList<Card> {
...
    public void render(Canvas canvas) {
       for (Card card : this) {
           // Do stuff
       }
    }
...
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Concurrent Modification exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496180/concurrent-modification-exception)

Comment: That question doesn't have an accepted answer. The iterator solutions suggested seem to have the same problem, that the iterator cannot handle concurrent modification.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ConcurrentModificationException despite using synchronized](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655362/concurrentmodificationexception-despite-using-synchronized)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an iterator and it's methods to add/remove items, for example:

```
public class Deck extends ArrayList<Card> {
...
    public void render(Canvas canvas) {

       Iterator<Card> it = iterator();
       while (it.hasNext()) {
           Card card = it.next;
           // Do stuff
           // remove card
           it.remove();
           // add new card
           it.add(new Card());
       }
    }
...
}
```

Comment: With or within synchronization?

Comment: Hmm, not getting it. What happens if an item is removed after the iterator calls hasNext()? I don't see how this resolves the concurrency problem.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @gipinani Why do you say it does not provide an answer? He is doing a for loop, modifies the list and has a ConcurrentModificationException. By using an iterator and the add/remove methods he could change the list while iterating

Comment: I tried that but unfortunately the iterator has the same concurrency problem when removing items. I ended up spamming "synchronised" all over the place, which seems to have resolved the issue, although my understanding of the keyword is still so so.

Comment: @schopy because just as a good question has code, so should a good answer. This answer is of no use to someone who doesn't know what an iterator is for example.