# Concurrent modification exception when save

Tags: java, jpa, concurrentmodification

When I save a list of added elements I get a concurrent modification exception. Below is the code of the save method called:

```
listAta listata = em.findbyid(id);
for (adressata ad : getInstance().getList()) {
    em.merge(ad);
}
em.merge(listata);
em.flush();
```

The line that caused the exception is `for (adressata ad : getInstance().getList())`

Below is the entity data:

```
@ManyToOne((fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
@JoinColumn(name="id_list" , nullable=false)
private ListAta listAta;
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: the line causing the problem is `em.merge(ad);` (it's modifying the list that is (con)currently being iterated), the one complaining it the for loop like explained in this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496180/concurrent-modification-exception

Comment: sorry but i don't undrestand the solution gived in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496180/concurrent-modification-exception

Comment: What is `getInstance().getList()`? How is it related to `adressata` and `ListAta`? Does changing the for loop to `for (adressata ad : new ArrayList<>(getInstance().getList()))` help? (there is a chance you have an actual multi threaded problem, maybe the related question isn't so much related as I thought)

Comment: You have added CascadeType.MERGE to the association so (if the rest of your code is correct)  you do not need to call  em.merge(ad) for each individual item. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Alan Hay : i use em.merge(ad) to update the entity after modification

Comment: zapl : the getInstance().getList() will get the list of adressata of listata