# Concurrent Modification Exception while adding elements to ArrayList recursively

Tags: java, recursion, arraylist, collections, subsequence

Getting Concurrent Modification Exception while adding elements to ArrayList recursively.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Hello {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str = sc.next();
        
        System.out.println(gss(str));
    }

    public static ArrayList<String> gss(String str) {
        if(str.length() == 0){
            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            list.add("");
            return list;
        }
        
        ArrayList<String> list = gss(str.substring(1));
        for(String temp : list){
            list.add(str.charAt(0)+temp);  // Problem  
        }
        
        return list;
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to avoid Concurrent Modification by adding `list.addAll(list.stream().map(temp -> str.charAt(0)+temp).collect(Collectors.toList()));`

Comment: Are you sure you want to add new elements to the list instead of modifying them?

Comment: Yes. @Amongalen

Comment: Can you provide an example of input and expected output?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Concurrent Modification exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496180/concurrent-modification-exception)

Comment: For an input string "abc"
Output must be an arraylist of its subsequences like [ , a, b, c, ab, ac, ....]
@javadev

Comment: This has nothing to do with recursion. You simply can't add to a list you are iterating.

Comment: @AndyTurner True, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solution: To just form new ArrayList at each call stack and return it.

```
import java.io.*;

import java.util.*;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str = sc.next();
    
    System.out.println(gss(str));
}

public static ArrayList<String> gss(String str) {
    if(str.length() == 0){
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("");
        return list;
    }
    
    ArrayList<String> list = gss(str.substring(1));
    ArrayList<String> listToReturn = new ArrayList<>();
    
    for(String temp : list){
        listToReturn.add(temp);
    }
    for(String temp : list){
        listToReturn.add(str.charAt(0) + temp);    
    }
    
    return listToReturn;
}

}
```

I have recently come across this [blog](https://www.java67.com/2015/10/how-to-solve-concurrentmodificationexception-in-java-arraylist.html).

Which says, It uses a transient variable called `modCount`, which keeps track of how many times a list is modified structurally. Structural modifications are those that change the size of the list, which may affect the progress of iteration and may yield incorrect results. Both `Iterator` and `ListIterator` uses this field to detect unexpected change. Other methods of List which structurally modify List also uses this method e.g. `add(), remove()`.

**Cause:** The real cause of `ConcurrentModficationException` is inconsistent `modCount`. When you are iterating over `ArrayList` then Iterator's `next()` method keep track of `modCount`. If you modify the collection by adding or removing element then `modCount` will change and it will not match with the expected `modCount`, hence Iterator will throw `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Comment: You can `listToReturn.addAll(list)`